# What is *& doing here? How do I change it to get a code as just void binaryTree::insert(binaryNode *root,string value)? Is it possible?

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, binary-search-tree

```
void binaryTree::insert(binaryNode *&root,string value)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        root = CreateNode(value);
    else if( value > root->data )
        insert (root->right,value);
    else if( value < root->data )
        insert (root->left,value);
}
```

Comment: At a guess, [tag:c++]? But I shouldn't *have* to guess. Please edit your question and add a language tag.

Answer (score 0):

`binaryNode *&` means a reference to a pointer to type `binaryNode`. Because it is a reference, this statement `root = CreateNode(value);` will modify what `root` refer to instead of changing `root` itself.

so, if you replace it with `binaryNode *`, that statement won't work, because you just modified `root` on this stack frame and this variable will be destroyed when the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
void binaryTree::insert(binaryNode **root,string value)
{
    if(*root==nullptr)
        *root = CreateNode(value);
    else if( value > *root->data )
        *root = insert (*root->right,value);
    else if( value < *root->data )
        *root = insert (*root->left,value);

    return root;
}
```

Or have the function return the pointer to the caller:

```
binaryNode *binaryTree::insert(binaryNode *root,string value)
{
    if(root==nullptr)
        root = CreateNode(value);
    else if( value > root->data )
        root = insert (root->right,value);
    else if( value < root->data )
        root = insert (root->left,value);

    return root;
}
```

Obviously, in the latter, calling insert() would be a little different as you would need to assign the result to the first argument:

```
someTree = binaryTree::insert(someTree, someString);
```